# Нахождение процентного соотношения кол-ва букв "а" в строке

Tags: c, строки, символы

Задание состоит из 3 частей:
1)определить, сколько букв в строке
2)сколько букв "а" в этой строке
3)сколько букв а в процентах в этой строке
Первые два задания выполнены, однако в третьем не хочет находить проценты, а именно делить j на кол-во букв в строке. В чем проблема?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {
    int i, j, ar, t;
    char* str = "ya sam sebe i nebo i luna";
    char findL = 'a';
    printf("ya sam sebe i nebo i luna\n");
    printf("kol-vo simvolov: %d\n", strlen(str));

    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        if (str[i] == findL) j++;

    {
        printf("bukv %c : %d\n", findL, j);
        ar = j / strlen(str) * 100;
        printf("bukv a v stroke %d procentov\n", ar);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Неужели любой символ это буква? (а ведь в задании просят **число букв**). А также, 2 раза вызывать одну и ту же функцию (strlen) с теми же данными как-то глупо, не находите?

Comment: на самом деле, задание просит число символов. Число букв было написано... просто потому что:) Я только учу С и потому пока реализация задания такая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Целочисленное деление.

```
ar = 100 * j / strlen(str);
```